# Git hook and ssh Agent Forwarding

Tags: git, ssh, hook, forwarding, ssh-agent

I've got a remote development server with a git repository.

When I push from my local machine to this dev server it runs the git hook after-receive to push the develop branch on a heroku staging server.

My identity is forwarded to the development server, here is my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
  User myuser
  ConnectTimeout 15
  ServerAliveInterval 45
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How can I make it used by the hook to deploy on heroku ?

For the moment it does not use the agent forwarded but uses the development server ssh identity. We want to avoid the ssh key on the server as many person are pushing.

Many thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

So I added this in the profile of my shell session (profile or bashrc conf for example) and it does the job.

```
if [ ! -d /tmp/501 ]; then
  mkdir /tmp/501
  ssh-agent -a /tmp/501/ssh-agent.socket
fi

SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/501/ssh-agent.socket
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Hopefully that will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're connecting to the development server with your user **myuser**, the git hook should also be running as **myuser**.

If you've not already created ssh-keypairs for connecting to your **heroku staging server** from your **development server** for user **myuser**, you need to do that.

```
<Login to your development server as myuser>
ssh-keygen -t rsa
<Upload the public key onto your heroku server's authorized_keys file>
```

You need to create a similar ~/.ssh/config on your development server for the user **myuser** that can be used by the hook to connect to the staging server.

And to confirm you can try this command from your development server to see if it can login into the staging server:

```
ssh heroku-staging-server
```

That should be all :)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was actually curious on forwarding the same agent through many ssh sessions without creating keys in the middle (which are actually new agents).